# Excel VBA - Check cell whether it contains piece of text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check a range of cells for a certain piece of text. This text is always in my document, except it's cell is variable (column is always B). So I check a range from 1:75 whether any cells contain a piece of text, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim FoundRange As Range
Set FoundRange = Cells.Find("5/7 binnen 4h")
Range("I" & EmptyCell + 2).Value = ... (value of cell I on same row as B)
```

Cell I'm looking for always contains this text `Onderhoud 5/7 binnen 4h` but its position can vary, that's why I just need to check whether it contains any of it. When I find that cell, I need the value I on the same row.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Hmm taking a closer look into the Instr function, it can't equal 1, it will be higher. I was under the impression this function was 1 = true, 0 = false.

Comment: `Instr` returns the position of the first occurrence of the string you are looking for in the string you are searching

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you not just search for the substring?

```
Sheet1.Cells.Find("string to find")
```

Will return the a range containing the string (or nothing if the string can't be found.

For example

```
Public Sub Macro1()
Dim FoundRange As Range

Set FoundRange = Sheet1.Cells.Find("5/7 binnen 4h")

' display the cell address to the user
MsgBox FoundRange.Address


' put the found value in column i in the same row as the found text in a known location ($C$1 in this case)
Sheet1.Range("$C$1").Value = Sheet1.Cells(FoundRange.Row, 9).Value

' put the found value in four columns to the right in the same row as the found text in a known location ($C$1 in this case)
Sheet1.Range("$C$2").Value = FoundRange.Offset(0, 4).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: So it will search my entire sheet looking for `5/7 binnen 4h`?

Comment: Yes, much faster than looping through looking at cells individually.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: as in copy the value from found range to one cell to the right?

Comment: So, the value will always be in column B. When it's found, B5 for example, I want the value of I5. (I contains the second column I need)

Comment: Not sure if you mean it's always column i or if it's a particular offset from the found value so I've added both to the example.

Comment: Yes, it's always column B and I :) (B contains the text, I contains a value I need to copy somewhere else)

Comment: ok then the above should work for you - it takes the row based on the result of the found cell and explicitly sets the column to 9 (I).

Comment: What happens if it's Nothing? I get an error, how could I work around it?

Answer (score 3):

This is too much to fit into a comment, so posting it as an answer...

You should be careful when using `Find()` with just a single argument: if you've previously used `Find()` in your code and (eg) specified an argument `lookat:=xlWhole` then you may not get the results you expect, particularly if you're looking for a substring of a cell's value.  Settings passed to Find() are persistent: if you don't specify an argument then it may be carried over from the previous use.

As an example (working with a sheet containing the text "hello tom" in B4:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim f

    Set f = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(what:="tom", lookat:=xlPart)
    Report f

    Set f = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(what:="tom", lookat:=xlWhole)
    Report f

    Set f = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("tom")
    Report f

End Sub

Sub Report(f)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print f.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Running this gives:

```
$B$4
not found
not found
```

I seem to recall this is also the case if you've used Find() "manually" and then use it in code later in the same session (didn't test though).

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know that. Dumb bit of design there!

Comment: That actually makes sense.  It must default to find an exact match of the cell contents, so if you specify `lookat:=xlWhole` or if you leave that blank, it will try to match and "tom" is not an exact match for "hello tom".  It is a partial match, which is why `lookat:=xlPart` would work.